# How to rotate multiple objects towards one point?

Tags: modeling

Hello fellow blenderers,

I would like to ask if there is a way to rotate multiple objects towards one point. In my case of sunflower, it is the central point of the flower head. (See the picture below).

[image: Sonflower seeds distribution]

If you observe the image below, the central seeds are rotated more towards the centre which I would like to achieve by some multiple object rotation towards one point, however I can't figure how or if it is possible at all.

[image]

I was struggling to model the distribution of sunflower seeds, finally made som progress, but this attitude might be wrong in general (I ran the script from Brecht here - [Organic yet accurate modeling with the golden spiral](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/organic-yet-accurate-modeling-with-the-golden-spiral) , added particles, with hair settings, with smaller particles in central part, then convert the particles to objects and deformed them to semispherical shape with latice deformer) If you can share your idea, I wouldn't mind :)

Thx a lot

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps DupliVerts are too inflexible for what you need, but their ability to orient objects according to the parent object's vertex normals certainly makes it easy to have duplicates point toward the center, as illustrated here:
 [image]

To make the above, simply parent the master cone (in center) to the spiral, then go to the spiral's Properties->Object tab, where you will find a Duplication category (in red box above). Select Verts, then check Rotation (in green box above). Then simply rotate the master cone to re-orient all the other cones however you want. Be aware that whether-or-not the master cone has its rotation applied (Ctrl-a) makes a difference; try both ways to see which suits in this instance.

Also know that for finer detail and ability to scale seeds differently, you could do a Make Duplicates Real for all the DupliVerts, then give each a Track To constraint oriented toward an empty at the center.

By the way, the curve was created via Add Curve->Extra Objects, then converted to mesh for this use. You might need to turn Extra Objects on in User Prefs.

Comment: Please expand your question and explain how to make DupliVerts and how to point them at the center.

Comment: Expanded it as requested, let me know if more is needed

Comment: Thx for the answer. Although it doesn't solve my particular problem (as sunflower seeds are not distributed alongside the spiral), it's always good to know new tricks. I am really glad I've learned something new.

BTW. How did you manage to get all the cones to the spiral? Are they all sprouting hair objects, or is there another method how to achieve it? And are they somehow parented to master cone in the centre? Would you please mind to explain this cone-spiral relation? Thank you

Comment: DupliVerts are sort of a primitive particle/hair system. You don't have to put them on a spiral, you can put them on any shape, then select the cone and then shift-select the shape, then parent the cone to the shape by pressing Ctrl-p. Then click as illustrated in the red and green boxes above - and instantly your shape will be covered in cones (or seeds, etc.). The caveat here is that in Blender you cannot manually set vertex normals; they are automatic, and the cones (or seeds) will orient toward that automatically determined normal. Try compounding curves to emulate the seed pattern.

Comment: Cool... didn't know about this feature. Thank you once again for adding a puzzle piece to my (still quite limited) blender knowledge :)

Answer (score 5):

Since all of your seeds are one object, first you have to separate them.

1. In *Edit mode* press <kbd>P</kbd> > *By loose parts*.
2. In object mode, select all the flower seeds with <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to Geometry*.
4. Add a Empty in the center of the flower <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > *Empty* (any of empty types will work).
5. Select one of the flower seed objects. Add a *[Track To](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Tracking/Track_To)* constraint. Proprieties window > Constraints > *Add Object Constraint*
6. Set the Track To constraint's **Target** to the empty. Set **To** to be **Z**, and **Up** to be **X**
7. Select all of the flower seeds, with the seed with the constraint selected last (as the active object). Press <kbd>space bar</kbd> and search for *Copy Constraints to Selected Objects*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution suits my needs perfectly. Anyway, looking at the possibilities, I am still not sure how to evaluate world - local space, but trial error method soved it :)