# Set particles(hair) at equal distance from each other

Tags: particles

I have curve plane. I want to  set hemispheres at equal distance from each other ( more than 5000 hemispheres ). How i can do that Blender 2.8?

EDIT:

[image]

I need to do this yellow part

Comment: 'Grid' as 'distribution' option (emitter particle system for face or volume)?

Comment: For the first, curve plane - is hemisphere too ( When i understand, i'll try another grid ). U asked about emitter particle, so it means that i must use this particle ( i thought hair system ).

Comment: Some pictures of what you want to do could help

Comment: So you need some fractal distribution here https://media.treehugger.com/assets/images/2012/08/71044124-th.jpg this is not native in Blender (or.. this is already an answer somewhere?). Maybe this distribution can be done using Animation Nodes or with Python.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/organic-yet-accurate-modeling-with-the-golden-spiral