# Creating 3D Blender Objects using the Fibonacci Sequence or Math

Tags: scripting, add-on, blend-files, mathematics

I would like to create objects using the fibonacci sequence. such as the following:
[image]
[image]

I have checked online and saw this add-on https://blendermarket.com/products/fibonarray

It seems kinda outdated and i am not sure if they work for MAC OS. is there anyone who can refer me to an add on that is updated or a blender file that I can start with? Much appreciated.

Comment: There are quite a few posts about this subject, but a bit of reading is involved there are multiple techniques. Maybe start here:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/organic-yet-accurate-modeling-with-the-golden-spiral/1376#1376

Comment: Check this Geometry nodes demo https://download.blender.org/demo/geometry-nodes/erindale_still-life_geometry-nodes_demo.blend

Comment: @Crantisz: this is a real clear and easy to understand node tree.... :D +1

Comment: IMO Fib is always an interesting subject, & despite closing as dupe would really like to see any new methods to create fractals. Consider adding a bounty to fractals question linked, or an answer using demo linked..

Comment: @Crantisz wow thanks for this! do you have documentation for this? seems quite complicated

Comment: @batFINGER this group likes to close the questions fast disappointingly

Comment: Search for geometry nodes.