# How can i get design(texture) as shown in image

Tags: modeling

I want to create a micro-circle texture design as shown on reference image on a light diffuser, but I have no idea how to achieve this

[enter link description here](https://we.tl/t-10sR8BFLCZ)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you want to search for "phyllotaxis"

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like that:

Create a circle, extude inwards, loopcut:

[image]

Select all, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide* and choose an *Iterations* value of 1:

[image]

Press <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and activate *Offset Relative*:

[image]

Move up the new faces:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, rework the topology:

[image]

Comment: hello buddy @moonboots i try but I'm struggling to achieve the desired result of having all circles within a circular shape be of equal size. Is there a method to ensure uniform circle dimensions

Comment: Yes not sure how to do it....

Answer (score 1):

We can have this kind of result using a normal map:

[image]

[image]

A way to make it is to use geometry nodes, starting from the formula [indicated here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1394/19156) for instance.

[image]

The first part of the node tree above, simply implement the indicated algorithm to a set of points.

Then, this second part:

[image]

uses a grid with some high resolution and search the proximity of the grid points to the phyllotaxis positions calculated before.

From this proximity distance, it calculates the coordinates for a little sphere around the phyllotaxis point.

Once done, apply the gn modifier, UV unwrap the mesh (project from view, bounds) and bake the normals (with 'object' option gives a better result).

You can after that use the normal map for instance like this:

[image]

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: Very nice indeed

Comment: @RobinBetts hi and thanks. I've not found any way to model that properly... do you think this is possible respecting wanted proximities?

Comment: Tempted to go and have a look at @Erindale Woodford  's  chapters on phyllotaxis .. I can't recall whether there's a route to manifold,  glass-shadable topo, there.